# Can WLOG be used here?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Suppose $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_j$ and $q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_k$ are two sequences of prime numbers and $p_1p_2\cdots p_j=q_1q_2\cdots q_k$. Suppose also that both sequences are nondecreasing. Prove that the two sequences must be same, i.e $j=k$ and $p_i=q_i$ for all $i$, $1\le i\le j$.

If we try to prove this by induction on $j$, we let $j$ be arbitrary and then assume the statement holds for $j$, then we must prove it holds for $j+1$. We assume the premises for $j+1$ and an arbitrary $k$, and then we must prove $j+1=k$.

Now, if we try to prove by contradiction by assuming $j+1\neq k$, can we assume without loss of generality that $j+1> k$?

At first I thought no we can't, because $j+1$ and $k$ have different "properties", we have made different assumptions about them. For example we have assumed the statement holds for $j$, but we have made no assumptions about $k$.

But then I thought, why could we not use WLOG, since $j+1$ and $k$ are both just arbitrary positive integers?

Note: Im not looking for a solution to the problem, I want to understand the use of WLOG better

Comment: I'm being over-opinioned here, so don't take this too seriously, but the use of "WLOG" is basically a bad habit: it is an abbreviation for "without loss of generality" and is followed by some assertion "we may assume that...", so it is the claim that some special case(s) of the result being claimed imply the general result. Where that is obviously true, one can say why in a few words, and where it is not obvious, one should not use "WLOG". Either way, it is better not to use it.

Comment: In terms of the problem you are considering, I think it is a little tidier to use induction on $\mathrm{min}\{j,k\}$ rather than $j$. Of course, the problem is symmetric in $j$ and $k$, so one could, by symmetry, assume that $j\leq k$...

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "the problem is symmetric in $j$ and $k$"? I know what symmetry means but I don't know how to apply it in this case, where we have two arbitrary variables from the same set, and we have an induction hypothesis on the other one

Comment: The problem states that you have two nondecreasing sequences of primes $(p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_j)$ and $(q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_k)$ satisfying $p_1\ldots p_j = q_1\ldots q_k$. Swapping the $p$ sequence with the $q$ sequence swaps $j$ and $k$. Alternatively, the problem is "given two finite nondecreasing sequences of primes show that if the product of all the terms in one sequence is equal to the product of all the terms in the other, then they are equal." and we are simply insisting that the shorter sequence is labelled $(p_1,\ldots,p_j)$ if they are not of the same length.

Comment: @bobbyJames How did you get the idea that this can (or should) be proved by induction on $j$ ?